# Through php how can I close an active ssh connection which is created by php ssh2_connect?

Tags: php, ssh

I created an ssh connection using the following code.

```
    $connection = ssh2_connect($masterIp, 22);

    // authenticating the remote server connection with credentials
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password);

    // secure ftp connection to create directory if not exist
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
```

After completing the operations I need to close $connection, $sftp.
How can I safely close the connections. Can I use unset() function?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unset should suffice.

In PHP, when resources go out of scope or become unset, they are automatically closed (they should be anyway, unless the extension breaks the standard PHP model).

(Well, it will only be garage collected and thus closed when all references to the resource are destroyed)

Comment: Hmm, really? [Can I close a file by unsetting the handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10928892/367456)

Comment: @hakre Definitely an interesting thread.  I've always assumed (and I know I've read it somewhere, though I doubt anywhere authoritative) that PHP closes resources once all references to them are gone.

Comment: There is something like that [in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) (linked on one of the answers over there already), but it's unclear whether that means the handle is closed or not.

Comment: @hakre Yeah I wish the manual was clearer.  "freed by the garbage collector" seems to imply "closed and then freed", but by no means a safe assumption to make.  I've been going through PHP source for the last 30 minutes, but the GC code is quite difficult for me to follow.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure that your SSH session is properly closed consider using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). It sends all the SSH packets necessary to close the packet with the destructor and if you don't want to use that has a $ssh->disconnect().

Makes for much more portable code too.

Answer (score 1):

The SSH connection is opened until closed:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit;');
```

There is no explicit `ssh2_close` command.

The chances are good that `unset` will terminate the network connection as well. At least when the PHP process ends, the connection should get automatically closed.

Comment: This is wrong. You will get a Segmentation Fault when doing it this way:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118475/segmentation-fault-on-fopen-using-sftp-and-ssh2

The correct solution is to use the ssh2_disconnect() function:

https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.ssh2-disconnect.php

Comment: @HerbertMaschke Yes, good point. That's likely due to newer PHP versions, at that time this did not yet exist.