# Can I close a file by unsetting the handle?

Tags: php, resources

I'm a little puzzled if I can spare the `fclose` command by just unsetting the variable that carries the handle?

```
$handle = fopen($file);
...
fclose($handle);

... // script goes on for a long
```

Compared with:

```
$handle = fopen($file);
...
unset($handle);

... // script goes on for a long
```

Insights anyone?

Comment: I wouldn't trust it to work consistently across OSes (just a gut feeling though; I have no evidence either way)

Comment: Just curious: what is the reason you would choose `unset` above `fclose`?

Comment: Pekka is right, i tried `echo '$fp is resource = '.(is_resource($fp) ? 'true': 'false');` It returns false on W2K machine, and in others it returns true

Comment: @SanjaySurani: That is only a proof that your W2K PHP binary is broken and nothing more. `is_respource` should always return `TRUE` if `$fp` is a resource. Better check you opened the file successfully.

Comment: @hakre, yes it may be a case you are right, but I used fclose for both, and I was wondering why it difers. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @SanjaySurani: Good point. I always thought that flcose will close it.

Answer (score 3):

> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend Engine, a resource with no more references to it is detected automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector.

Consider the implications of this.  It's safe to assume that all traces of the variable are gone after the garbage collection.  In other words, at the end of PHP's execution, if PHP is not still tracking the reference, how would it close it?  Thus, it seems fairly logical that it would close it when the garbage collector eats it.

This is a bad logical argument though because it assumes that garbage collections happens either immediately or shortly after unset and that PHP does not keep hidden references to variables that no longer exist in user land.

---

A more compelling case though could be a potential behavioural flaw if PHP did not close file handles when they go out of scope.  Consider a daemon of some kind that opens lots of files.  Now consider if fclose is never called.  Instead, variables are allowed to fall out of scope or unset is explicitly called on them.

If these file handles were not closed, this long running daemon would run out of file handles.

---

Potentially behavior specific test script:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect(...);

if ($db) {
    echo "Connected\n";
    sleep(5); //netstat during this just for paranoia
    unset($db);
    echo "Unset\n";
    sleep(5); //netstat during this and the connection is closed
}
```

On both Windows 7 and Debian 6, the connection has been closed after the unset.

Obviously though, this only proves that on my specific machines with my specific PHP version will this work.  Has no meaning on file handles or the like :).

---

**Am searching the PHP source now for hard proof**

Comment: Sockets are not necessarily handled the same as regular files. Does not make sense to handle differently, but PHP often does not make sense.

Comment: "Has no meaning on file handles or the like :)." Yeah...  Am trying to follow the code through the garbage collection/resource clobbering path now.

Answer (score 2):

PHP docs hint that all resources with no remaining references are "freed", I assume for file handles this would include closing the file.

Simple test case:

```
$f = fopen("test.php", "r");
if (!flock($f, LOCK_EX)) {
  print("still locked\n");
  exit;
}
unset($f);
sleep(5);
print("goodbye\n");
```

(I've saved this as `test.php`, so it is locking itself; might need to change the filename in the `fopen()` to some existing file otherwise)

Run the script twice within 5 seconds; if you get "still locked", then apparently unsetting the handle did not release the lock. In my test, I did *not* get "still locked", so apparently unsetting the handle *at least* releases the lock, though it would seem silly to release locks upon garbage collection, but not close the file.

Comment: [Resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), section "Freeing resources"

Comment: Does freeing a resource in PHP will close the file-handle?

Comment: Docs don't say, but it makes no sense not to.

Answer (score 1):

`unset($handle)` will destroy the `$handle` variable, but it won't close the file being pointed by `$handle`. You still need to call `fclose()` to close the file.

Comment: I find it hard to proof that because after unsetting the handle, I can't use `fclose()` any longer, right?

Comment: @hakre What I mean is use `fclose($handle)` and not `unset($handle)`.

Comment: Obviously, but I'm concerned about the reasoning, not what is better.

Answer (score 0):

some research:

`fclose` makes `$handle` to be `resource(5) of type (Unknown)`
while

`unset` makes it `NULL`.

and after `fclose` php consumes 88 bytes of memory more.

so: they are different =)

Comment: Using memory to verify that. I'd say interesting, but this needs more elaboration so you remove side-effects that are imagineable.

Comment: i've used `memory_get_usage()` to get it

Comment: `unset` makes it `Undefined`, not `NULL`.