# Segmentation fault on fopen using sftp and ssh2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssh, segmentation-fault, sftp

I have a php system running on **AWS** and a class that upload a xlsx file on external server using **shh2** and **sftp**. 
This code worked fine until last upgrade of aws package **openssh-clients-6.6.1p1-31.62** and **openssh-server-6.6.1p1-31.62** by this time I have a **segfault** during **fopen**.
Fopen create a file on external server.
Here the code:

```
$stream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$this->sftp$remote_file", 'w');
```

Then I use $stream to write the content, but the code stop on fopen bacause a segfault.
I don't find anything about this problem, I think the problem is the new upgrade of opnessh, because the php code isn't changed.
Any idea?

Comment: This is a big problem. Surely no one but us has not faced it ...

Comment: I'm having the same effect (segfault) on a Debian 8 machine. It started after I installed updates: 
Start-Date: 2016-12-14  12:53:53
Commandline: apt-get upgrade
Upgrade: 
apt:amd64
libapache2-mod-php5:amd64
php5-mysql:amd64
python-urllib3:amd64
php5-common:amd64
php5-curl:amd64
apt-utils:amd64
php5-readline:amd64
libapt-inst1.5:amd64
php5:amd64
libapt-pkg4.12:amd64
php5-cli:amd64
python-requests:amd64
php-pear:amd64
php5-intl:amd64

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the answer here on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40972584/2520795

It seems since this PHP update, you have to surround your host part (result of `ssh2_sftp()`) with `intval()`:

```
$handle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp)."/path/to/directory");
```

In my case there was a `fopen` instead of an `opendir`, but the solution is the same.

Answer (score 8):

You may experience "segmentation fault" issue even with `intval($sftp)` solution if you're closing connection with `ssh2_disconnect()`. The right solution is to close SFTP connection before closing SSH2-connection by `unset($sftp)` or `$sftp = null`. Here's my fully working example of reading remote file:

```php
if (!$ssh2_connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port)) {
    die("Failed to connect\n");
}
if (!ssh2_auth_password($ssh2_connection, $username, $password)) {
    die("Failed to login\n");
}
if (!$sftp_connection = ssh2_sftp($ssh2_connection)) {
    die("Failed to open SFTP session\n");
}
if (!$fh = fopen("ssh2.sftp://".intval($sftp_connection).$path, 'r')) {
    die("Failed to open file\n");
}
while (($s = fgets($fh)) !== false) {
    echo $s;
}
fclose($fh);
unset($sftp_connection);
if (!ssh2_disconnect($ssh2_connection)) {
    die("Failed to disconnect\n");
}
```

P.S. Also instead of "segmentation fault" you may see something like:

> php: channel.c:2570: _libssh2_channel_free: Assertion `session' failed.
>
> Aborted

My solution solves it.

Answer (score 3):

In our case, the intval() didn't solve the segmentation fault. However, changing the call format did work:

```
fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$username}:{$password}@{$host}:{$port}/{$absolutePath}/{$filename}", 'w');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but I have found this [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73524) (see post from: [2016-12-15 09:47 UTC] by ovoelker at wavecon dot de)

1. add php5-dev for compiling pecl module
2. reinstall ssh2 pecl module.
3. restart apache and work well

Answer (score 0):

ssh2 caused a segfault in my case (php8) during shutdown, after the usage of the `$dir = dir(...)` function without calling `$dir->close();`. I assume this is the same behaviour if `opendir()` is used.